# Insert char* as vector<byte> in sqlite

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to insert a `char*` (which was read from a file) into SQLite Database as a byte array (`vector<byte>`)  to avoid being viewed explicitly.

Below is my code to read the file and have it in buffer as byte array,

```
void DataBaseUtils::readFileContents(string filePath)
{
    ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file) {
        cerr << "An error occurred opening the file\n";
        return;
    }
    file.seekg(0, ifstream::end);
    size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0);

    char *buffer = new char[size];
    file.read(buffer, size);

    vector<byte> vByteArray(reinterpret_cast<byte>(buffer), size);

    mBlobBuffer = (char*)&vByteArray;

    mCharBuffer = buffer;

}
```

Below is where I insert the data into my source code,

```
    std::stringstream strmInsert("");

    strmInsert << "INSERT or IGNORE INTO SAMPLETABLE(NAME, CONTENTS) VALUES(" << "'" << getName() << "'," << '?' << ")";

    string sInsert = strmInsert.str();
    char *strInsert = &sInsert[0];
    char *query1 = strInsert;

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;

    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbfile, query1, -1, &stmt, NULL);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        cerr << "prepare failed: " << sqlite3_errmsg(dbfile) << endl;
    }
    else {
        // SQLITE_STATIC because the statement is finalized
        // before the buffer is freed:
        rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 1, mCharBuffer /*mBlobBuffer*/, size, SQLITE_STATIC);
        if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
            cerr << "bind failed: " << sqlite3_errmsg(dbfile) << endl;
        }
        else {
            rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
            if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
                cerr << "execution failed: " << sqlite3_errmsg(dbfile) << endl;
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

In my `sqlite3_bind_blob` statement, if I use `mCharBuffer`, the query runs properly but if I use `mBlobBuffer`, application crashes sometimes and works sometimes,  without any pattern.

How do I resolve it and insert the file contents as a BLOB data into CONTENTS column.

[Sample Image to show BLOB data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls0o2.jpg)

[Sample Image to show Plain text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgrdj.jpg)

Edit : Added images for clarity. I'd like to have the data as BLOB as first image rather than plain text in second (ABCD..)

Comment: What do you use `mBlobBuffer` for and how is it defined?

Comment: `char* mCharBuffer = 0;`

`char* mBlobBuffer = 0`

Both are defined as `char*`.

I need to store the file contents into a column of the DB. I don't want the data to be visible (it is visible if store it as a plain text (char*)) , hence I am trying to use it as a byte array.

Comment: Why do you have both `mBlobBuffer` and `mCharBuffer`? Do you really need both?

Comment: No, I don't, I have it only for debugging purposes.

Comment: Your assumption that BLOB data is unreadable is incorrect.

The data is the same text, just in a binary format.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, how do i save it in binary format without crashing the program. Is `vector<byte>` the right way to store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to obscure your text by storing the `vector<byte>` in the database because the `vector<byte>` object doees **not** contain your text. Not directly.

A `vector<byte>` is basically a few pointers (maybe 3) that point to your text and nothing else. Storing the vector simply stores those pointers.

The **only** way to obscure your text is to **encrypt** it.

One problem with this code is you casting `std::vector<byte>` to a `char*` when setting `mBlobBuffer`. Even if the vector was a `char*` (which it isn't) it gets destroyed at the end of the function. So `mBlobBuffer` points to nothing useful.

I would consider making `mCharBuffer` a *vector* and just using that. You avoid dynamic allocation that way. Something like this:

```
class DataBaseUtils
{
public:
    void readFileContents(string filePath);

private:
    // make this  std::vector
    std::vector<char> mCharBuffer;
};

void DataBaseUtils::readFileContents(string filePath)
{
    std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "An error occurred opening the file\n";
        return;
    }

    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    mCharBuffer.resize(file.tellg()); // no need to store the size elsewhere
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    if(!file.read(mCharBuffer.data(), mCharBuffer.size())) {
        std::cerr << "An error occurred reading the file\n";
        return;
    }

    // need to encrypt the contents of the vector here
}
```

Then, when you come to put it into the function:

```
rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 1, mCharBuffer.data(), mCharBuffer.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
```

The size is recorded in the vector.

Also you don't record when an error happens,I would *throw an exception* rather than just printing the error.

Comment: This will work but it will still simply put the file contents as plain text and not as a BLOB data. Is it possible to convert / store the data in the DB as a BLOB instead of a plain text.

And I have `mBlobBuffer` as a member variable and try to set and use it across after casting it. It works properly at times and doesn't otherwise which I couldn't rationalize why or how.

Comment: @DeenadayalanS I am not sure what you mean. Casting to `byte*` does not change the data in any way, it is still plain text. You can store plain text as blob data. Do you want to hide the data by making it unreadable?

Comment: @DeenadayalanS You can not cast a `vector` to a `char*` because the `vector` does not store its data internally, it stores a *pointer* to its data.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I don't want the data to be readable as a plain text but as a BLOB.

Comment: @DeenadayalanS BLOBs are still readable if you don't do something to the text to hide it. It sounds like you need to **encrypt** the data after reading it in from the file.

Comment: Added images in the question details for BLOB as well as TEXT. I need the data to be stored as BLOB (hidden and unreadable) instead of plain text.

For encryption, I use Sqlcipher to encrypt the complete DB as a whole.

Comment: @DeenadayalanS The bottom line is if you want the `BLOB` to be unreadable it needs to be encrypted. If you encrypt the database as a whole do you really need to also encrypt this `BLOB`?

Comment: @DeenadayalanS I suspect the **only** reason you can't see the text in one of your images is because you didn't store the text in the database, you stored your *vector* which does not directly contain your text.

Comment: Yes, I understand and prefer to store it the same way (as vector<byte>) to be unreadable. But the code worked some times and crashes sometimes and I wanted to understand why it was behaving in a weird way.

Comment: @DeenadayalanS You can't store `vector<byte>` it does **not** contain your text (not directly at least).

Comment: @DeenadayalanS The `vector<byte>` is basically `3` pointers, **nothing else**. That is all you are storing. But because you are reading and writing the entire length of the text you are going beyond the bounds of the `vector<byte>`

Comment: @DeenadayalanS The only way to hide the text is to encrypt it.

Comment: @DeenadayalanS Yes.